# how change the securitymanager to allow write in a guest Account? (Windows)

Tags: windows, security

I'm making a program, and it makes a .txt file where it saves information.

The problem is that using the Guest account, Windows doesn't allow me to save a .txt file.

I want to change the Guest account's permissions to allow these actions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File Text=new File("texto.txt");
        FileWriter Write=new FileWriter(Text,true);
        Write.write("txt");
        Write.close();
    }
```

ok, how can i save information in the Guest account???

must be way

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do? Where and how are you creating these files?

Comment: This sounds like a windows help desk question rather than a programming issue. You'll just want to google guest account file permissions for Windows. You may end up getting down-voted for this, if you do that would be why.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can make a .exe file to make that after these open your .jar with Java -jar name.jar
good luck!!

Comment: Exelent idea brother, hey i miss you, i will visit one day!!

Comment: haha man i'm so tired, life in this place is hard i need vacations, dile a mama que la quiero mucho, cuidate carnal y hechale ganas a programar yo te ayudo en lo que pueda Suerte wey!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You're barking up the wrong tree. The Java SecurityManager doesn't enforce this. Windows does.